# Inserting values into textarea after clicking buttons (Javascript only)

Tags: javascript

I have a text form with two buttons. After clicking on the buttons, I want to add text from the button (ie. the word HELLO or HELLO2) to the form:

```
<button type="button" onclick="addtext('HELLO');">Add HELLO</button>
<button type="button" onclick="addtext('HELLO2');">Add HELLO2</button>

<textarea id="postText"><textarea>
```

and a simple function:

```
<script>
function addtext(x) {
var e = document.getElementById('postText').value;
e += x;
}
</script>
```

But it doesn't work (error is 'x is not defined). I want to paste the words HELLO and HELLO2 into the textarea (keeping any existing textarea values). How to make it work without errors?

Comment: You need to pass a this reference to your function. Also, HELLO is appearing as a literal. It should be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: You need to quote the strings.

Comment: If you want to reference the button you need the this reference.

Comment: @mike: he's not using `this`, or referring to the buttons at all: he's trying to pass a string.

Comment: I know I realized it after and commented already that it is only necessary when you need tor reference the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks.. but how? :)
```

Change

```
addtext(HELLO);
```

and

```
addtext(HELLO2);
```

to

```
addtext('HELLO');
```

and

```
addtext('HELLO2');
```

### Why?

Strings must be in quotes. JavaScript before thought x was equal to the variable of HELLO and HELLO2 which didn't exist.

Also, add a slash so you end your definition of a text area: `</textarea>` and change your JS to

```
function addtext(x) {
var e = document.getElementById('postText');
e.value+=x;
}
```

### Why?

If you set e to a value then it'll be that static value and won't be able to change the actual value of the textarea. Also, some elements need closing tags.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RJPP3/)

Comment: Yes. But now could you explain *why*?

Comment: @DavidThomas Okay, even though it says in the comments and I quoted what he said.

Comment: because javascript thinks HELLO is a variable without the quotes.

Comment: `addtext(HELLO);` means passing the value of a variable called `HELLO` to the function. Since `HELLO` is undefined, you will have an error when referring to `x` in your function, because nothing is passed to it. `addtext('HELLO');` will pass the string `HELLO` to the function.

Comment: addtext('HELLO') and addtext('HELLO2') doesn't do anything after clicking on the button, no warnings either.. Could someone test it please?

Comment: Edit2 above works, the problem was with the function itself (even though logically your function is the same as mine..? ). Thank you.

Comment: @Gooden Your welcome. Also, your function's not the same. `e` is being set to a value rather than a dynamic element.